# how can I modify my mongodb/mongoose query so that it returns more detailed json?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my app I have a model for storing users. Each user can block other users, so I created an entry in this model that holds ids of blocked users:

```
...
blocked_user_ids: {type: [String]},
...
```

I also created an endpoint that allows me to get list of blocked users for a given `user_id`. Since I wanted to have each user's details on that list I had to do the following queries:

```
usersRoutes.get('/:id/blockedUsers/', functions.validateRequestsGET, function(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;

    async.auto({
        one: function(callback){
            findBlockedUsersIdsOfGivenUser(userId, callback);
        },
        two: ['one', function(callback, results){
            getBlockedUsersDetails(results.one, callback);
        }],
        final: ['one', 'two', function(callback, results) {
            res.status(200).send(results.two);
        }],
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            sendError(res, err);
            return;
        }
    });
});

function findBlockedUsersIdsOfGivenUser(userId, callback) {
    var query = User.findOne({_id: userId}).select("blocked_user_ids");
    query.exec(function(err, blockedUsersIds){
        if(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        return callback(null, blockedUsersIds.blocked_user_ids);
    });
}

function getBlockedUsersDetails(blockedUsersIds, callback) {
    var query = User.find({_id: {$in: blockedUsersIds}});
    query.exec(function(err, blockedUsersDetails) {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        return callback(null, blockedUsersDetails);
    });
}
```

That worked well and returned me a json where each json node held information about specific user.

However, now my model changed, currently I had to change the string array into a structure:

```
...
blocked_user_ids: [{
    user_id: {type: String, required: true},
    is_anonymous: {type: Boolean, required: true}
}],
...
```

and now, besides getting user information in my json, I need to modify my queries so that the output json contains information about the flag `is_anonymous` - I want to add the value of that flag to each json node that represents each user. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

So you can get the ids using *Array.map* and after you get the result add the *is_anonymous* property to each user.

```
function getBlockedUsersDetails(blockedUsersIds, callback) {
    // get all ids and also create users object for easier assigning of `is_anonymous` property
    var users = {};
    var ids = blockedUsersIds.map(function(a){
        users[a.user_id] = a.is_anonymous;
        return a.user_id;
    });
    // ids is same array you previously had as blockedUsersIds
    var query = User.find({_id: {$in: ids}});
    query.exec(function(err, blockedUsersDetails) {
        if(err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        //blockedUsersDetails.forEach(function(user, index){            
            //user.is_anonymous = users[user.user_id];
        //});

        blockedUsersDetails.forEach(function(user, index){            
            blockedUsersDetails[index].is_anonymous = users[user.user_id];
        });

        return callback(null, blockedUsersDetails);
    });
}
```

I haven't tried this code so expect some bugs or typos :)

Comment: thank you for this answer, I tried that and the code worked without any bugs or typos :) however, I do not see the flag `is_anonymous` in the output json, it only contains all `user` details... Is there anything else that maybe comes to your mind that I could try?

Comment: hm now when I'm thinking - it might be because I do not have the actual field `is_anonymous` in my user model - do you think that might be the reason?

Comment: thank you, I tried it, however even if in my database I store: `"blocked_user_ids" : [ { "is_anonymous" : true, "user_id" : "58...88c0", "_id" : ObjectId("586ab...c3") }, { "is_anonymous" : false, "user_id" : "586....8c0", "_id" : ObjectId("58...7a98a") } ]`, I'm still seeing a single entry json as an output and even there, the flag `is_anonymous` is not present :(

Comment: I also realized that in the output json field `user_id` is missing, I'm not sure if that information is crucial here or not